# Can I travel to UK using my Bulgarian Blue Card?

Tags: uk, bulgaria

If I am Bulgarian Blue Card holder, can I travel to UK using my Bulgarian Blue Card?

Comment: A residence permit is **not a travel document**. A passport based on citizenship is. As a general rule you must use your passport.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but it is not unreasonable to wonder whether the card can be used in conjunction with a passport to avoid needing a visa.  It can be used that way in Croatia, for example.

Comment: @phoog Yes, my intention was to **hint** that **citizenship** should always be given in such travel questions

Comment: @MarkJohnson that is a worthy goal, but I would counsel you not to get your hopes up!

Answer (score 5):

You can only use your Bulgarian residence permit (with your passport) to enter the UK without a visa if the card is for a *family member of an EU citizen* (член на семейството на гражданин на ЕС) and you are traveling with or joining that EU citizen.

Note that a blue card is a work permit, so it would not qualify. You will need a visa to visit the UK.

Comment: A blue card is definitely not a residence card for a family member of an EU citizen.

Comment: @phoog That's what I thought. But other people will read the question in the future so ideally the answer should be reasonably complete.

Comment: Of course.  I just would have added an additional sentence noting that and concluding therefore that in this case a visa is definitely necessary.  I already upvoted the answer, though, so don't edit it on my account.

Comment: A Blue Card is a **residence permit** with **special** privileged work conditions